# When should layers be implemented as separate units of deployment?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, data-access-layer, layer

When designing an application, at what point should the various layers (such as Presentation, Business Logic, and Data Access) be separated into different assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly you'll be distirbuting classes in different libraries if you want to provide your product in a way you can choose some final user wouldn't have access to the entire project's classes.

Think in a client-server application. Why you would want to distribute server classes to your customer if you've a cloud computing scenario? You'd prefer to distribute presentation and service client classes, packaged in server-independent assemblies. That's a good security practice too.

Another good point to separate in assemblies is to avoid to load a large assembly to an application domain (AppDomain). For example, if the usage of your program doesn't require image processing overtime, but maybe, a single operation per day would need to require imaging classes, you're saving processing time - when loading a large assembly to application domain - and memory because your application doesn't require an assembly that has all and, at the end of the day, your application has fewer memory usage.

In the arquitectural point of view, separating in assemblies would enforce good practices, thanks to the fact you'll be aware of not mixing layers because, for example, you shouldn't require business assemblies in your presentation assembly, so, no one has access to business logic directly from the user interface.

Finally, in terms of deployment, you save time as you can update a modular application with specific assemblies, easing the upload process or auto-update process, because download times are reduced, saving network traffic.

Comment: I was most interested in the latter part of this answer.

Comment: Well, I tried to cover many things on splitting in assemblies :) Happy to know it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like splitting my layers right at the begging of my project, not necessary into different assemblies but different folders.

I would then move the different layers into different assemblies when I require the use of a layer in a different project.

Once the layers are in different assemblies you need to worry about versioning and the sorts which can be quite cumbersome.

Comment: Your answer would be correct for a small project, but, now imagine that you're selling your product, and since you've it in a single, big assembly, you're exposing to your customers server-side specific details that are part of your company value, so your customers can create their own client-server solution with your "all-in-one assembly". Sure licensing would prevent that, but it's a security concern, because they can easly reverse-engineer your MSIL and see how your code works, and even, discover security issues...

Comment: True, it all depends on what type and size of project is being created. I would personally use WCF service and put my business logic there with my Data Access logic, the front end would then only have very basic logic and proberly the entities layer which gets used accross all layers. With smaller projects though I don't see the customer taking the time to really diassemble the project to see how it works or to hack it, but there are tools out there that you can use on your application to prevent this. Or at least make it more dificult.

Comment: Right. But instead of creating WCF services, just separate it in assemblies. You'd use WCF is you want to distribute your client and server in different tiers, but anyway, WCF is the door and you'd need to previously separate your classes in assemblies, so you'd be able to expose your business with service endpoints and consume them with clients. I believe organizing your code in a good way isn't a time cost, even in small projects. It's just a good practice that's going to save time in terms of maintain and distribute your code base.